# How to hide label in a Filled Input in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, textfield

2 questions : first) i have an BMI calculator here . so when the user wants to input her data like height and weight => when the input is filled the textfield widget still shows the label and i don't want that. and i really don't know what to do??
can you help me please???

and second) i want the lable of textfield that is unfilled yet to be shown in center of it's own space . but if you take a look at picture care fully you see that "Weight" label is at the start of the textfield and i don't want that. i want to be in center in the textfield.
and i also want that when the user inputs her/his data the inputed text be in the center of textfield. like here i input my height 178 => and this "178" is not in center of textfield!
please help me guys!

so here for example i expect when i input my height that height lable goes... and shouldn't be there any more... but it there unfortunately :( .

thank you for helping me for my 2 questions.
[image: take a look at this picture...]

and here is my code:

```
TextField(
                    controller: height_controller,
                    keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.center,
                      label: Text(
                        'Height',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first issue, if you want the label to not be visible when there has been some input, then you need to add a condition that will change when the onValueChanged method is triggered.

I.E.

```
var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            text = it
            visible = text.isEmpty()
        },
        label = {
            if (visible) {
                Text("Label",
                    style = TextStyle(
                        textAlign = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.Center).textAlign))
            }
                },
    )
```

For your second issue, to align the text inside your label for your TextField, you can use `LocalTextStyle.current` since it uses that by default.

```
TextField(
                    controller: height_controller,
                    keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.center,
                      label: Text(
                        'Height',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                            textAlign = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.Center).textAlign)),  // <--------
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```